# Is it possible to encrypt the username and password in the connection string in the web.config file (Visual Studio 2015, SQL Server 2014)

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, visual-studio-2015, web-config

So I have a connection string labeled as:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TBL_ClassServices" 
         connectionString="Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB; database=Assignment1; User Id=test; Password=test"
         providerName="System.data.sqlclient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I just want to encrypt the User Id and the Password without encrypting the whole connection string itself.  Is it possible, and if so, how would you encrypt it, and then decrypt it using aspx.cs (C# back-end) code.

Thanks

Comment: Where do you want to save your key, inside the C# code?

Comment: `aspnet_regiis ` ?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy.aspx

Comment: to be clear, you couldn't do it inside the connection strings. you could do it in appsettings though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a separate program to set the encrypted string into the config file and decrypt the string in your c# code whenever you need to read the connection string. Here is a helpful post for accomplishing this:
[Encrypt and decrypt a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202011/encrypt-and-decrypt-a-string)

Comment: thanks a lot.  helped me a lot